# Does app bundle id have to match firebase bundle id?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am changing my app's bundle id for some reason and I am using firebase, does the bundle id of the app have to match the bundle id in the firebase, in other words, can I change the bundle ID of my app without changing it on firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change it after adding it to the project.  The process to add an iOS app to Firebase requires a knowledge of the bundle ID you're using.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#register-app) clearly states:

> Make sure to enter the bundle ID that your app is actually using. The bundle ID value is case-sensitive, and it cannot be changed for this Firebase iOS app after it's registered with your Firebase project.

Comment: okay, so that's mean that I have to create a new firebase project, right?

Comment: You can create a new app within the same Firebase project if you want to keep using that same project.